# Generate all possible pairs and count frequency in Python

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency-analysis

I have a data frame of products (apple, pear, banana) sold across different locations (cities) within different categories (food and edibles).

I would like to count how many times any given pair of products appeared together in any category.

This is an example dataset I'm trying to make this to work on:

```
category <- c('food','food','food','food','food','food','edibles','edibles','edibles','edibles', 'edibles')
location <- c('houston, TX', 'houston, TX', 'las vegas, NV', 'las vegas, NV', 'philadelphia, PA', 'philadelphia, PA', 'austin, TX', 'austin, TX', 'charlotte, NC', 'charlotte, NC', 'charlotte, NC')
item <- c('apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana')

food_data <- data.frame(cbind(category, location, item), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For example, the pair "apple & banana" appeared together in the "food" category in "las vegas, NV", but also in the "edibles" category in "charlotte, NC". Therefore, the count for the "apple & banana" pair would be 2.

My desired output is count of pairs like this:

(unordered) count of apple & banana

2

(unordered) count of apple & pear

4

Anyone have an idea for how to accomplish this? Relatively new to R and have been confused for a while.

I'm trying to use this to calculate affinities between different items.

Additional clarification on output: My full dataset consists of hundreds of different items. Would like to get a data frame where the first column is the pair and the second column is the count for each pair.

Comment: Where is the code you tried to make it work with?

Comment: first, u r presenting an r dataframe in pandas. u should rewrite it in python format

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Great first attempt at a question. One more suggestion is to put your expected output in a code block. More information on [crafting a question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).